# Is there a limit to MySQL queries?

Tags: php, sql, database, mysql

I am trying to insert 10,000+ fields into my database? Is there a limit?

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO `_'.$test.'` (`user`, `pass`) VALUES ' . preg_replace($test, $replace, $final_check) . ';';
mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Every time I try to insert the data, it fails.

Comment: "it fails"? Is that all the error message you get? "Failed"? Or did you get something more specific? If you did, please post the entire error message, otherwise all we can say is "tough luck, it fails".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's your query. Make sure you are importing the right data, and it shouldn't fail.
Echo the $sql to test it.

```
echo $sql
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a packet size limit in the MySQL protocol. If your SQL statement exceeds that, it can't send it to the server. The limit was for a very long time 16Mb, but fairly recent versions have raised it higher.

Also, check that you are enclosing each row's worth of data in it's own parentheses.